# Minor ticks with only major tick labels are shown

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I would like to have minor ticks on a axis but show only major tick labels. For instance, minor ticks are [19, 20, 21, ... 40, 41] and major tick labels are [20, 25, 30, 35, 40]. How can I do it? the code below didn't do the job. I know one could use MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter like [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html). However, my values on the axis are a bit "strange" with the starting value is 19 (not 20) and end value is 41, which cause difficulty when using MultipleLocator.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(19.,41,23)
y = x**2
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

it gives me the following plot:
[image]

or `ax.set_xticklabels([20, 25, 30, 35, 40], minor=False)`
give me another plot:
[image]
How can I change my code to get what I need. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: use `FixedLocator`.  `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` are dangerous and should only be used rarely.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't really understand why is it difficult to use `MultipleLocator` in your example.

By adding these lines in your code

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(5)
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(1)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
```

You'll get this image, which I understood it is what you want (isn't it?):
[image]

---

In case you don't want the ticks to show below your range of data, define your ticks manually using the `FixedLocator`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

majorLocator   = FixedLocator(np.linspace(20,40,5))
minorLocator   = FixedLocator(np.linspace(19,41,23))
```

And you'll get this image:
[image]

Comment: Yes, the second solution is exactly what I want to have. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome answer, and great introduction to locators. Another note for anyone coming across this: using `ax.set_xticks` or `ax.set_yticks` will change the major-tick locator to `FixedLocator`, which may be a simpler way of doing that. **However**, I suppose because it is uncommon, there is no `ax.set_xminorticks` or `ax.set_yminorticks`... to manually pick minor ticks, they must be set with `FixedLocator` as in this post.